# assert() safety in multithreaded context

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

so I cannot seem to find solid info on whether assert is useable in a mulththreaded context.

logically to me it seems if an assertion fails the thread get shutdown but not the other threads?

or does the entire process get killed?

so  basically my question. is it safe to use assert in a multithreaded environment without leaking resources?

Comment: `without leaking resources` assert() terminate the program forcibly. Whether multithreaded or singlethreaded, you cannot free your resource. Basically, it's just for debugging. Do you really need to free resources?

Comment: Where did you look for this "solid info"? Is the man page not clear that it "terminates the program by calling `abort`"?

Comment: I was under the impression that threads do not get terminated at program shutdown if the function the thread is performing has not terminated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/assert) of `assert()`, it clearly states,

> The purpose of this macro is to help the programmer find bugs in his
>   program. The message "assertion failed in file foo.c, function
>   do_bar(), line 1287" is of no help at all to a user.

This means, it's only useful [and should be used] in a developing environment, not in production software. IMO, in development stage, you need not to worry about `leak`s caused by `assert()`. YMMV.

Once you finished debugging your code, you can simply *switch off* the `assert()` functionality by defining [`#define`] `NDEBUG`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say more than yes. If I'd see a multithreaded code without asserts I'd not trust it. If you simplify a bit its implementations to something like:

```
#define assert(x) if( !(x) ) abort()
```

You'll see that it does nothing special for thread-safety or thread-specific. It's your responsibility to provide race-free condition and if the assertion fails, the whole process is aborted.

Answer (score 0):

The entire process gets killed.  Assert will send the expression, source filename and line number to stderr and then call abort().  Abort() terminates the entire process.